# What is the Google's revenue share for Android in-app purchases?

Tags: android, google-play

I am thinking of publishing an "trial version" of my application and upsell to the full version using Android Market in-app payment. This is so that I can list my app for free ans reduce the initial download friction. However, I am trying to figure out how much money Google actually takes a cut for in-app billing transactions. Is it 30% + Check out processing fee (3-5%?) or some other number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&&answer=1153481

> The standard 30% transaction fee applies to in-app transactions on
>   Android Market.

Comment: So the Google Checkout fees don't apply here? http://checkout.google.com/seller/fees.html

Comment: AFAIK additional checkout fees don't apply for the android market, just the 30% . according to https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&&answer=112622 , if you sell something for 10$ in the android market, you get 7$.

Comment: Yes 30% is right ! This resource is the proof https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622?hl=en&ref_topic=3452890